# Appropriate situations for using classes and id's?

Tags: css

This might seem like a little bit of a nit picky question, but I feel it's rather important, and I really want some clarity for this (I can't seem to find much information about it)

Say for example we want a box that floats left, has a black background, and white text, is it better to do:

```
<div id="random-box">This is some content</div>
```

and have the CSS as:

```
#random-box { float: left; background-color: #000; color: #fff; }
```

or is it better to do:

```
<div class="float-left random-box">This is some content here</div>
```

and have the CSS as:

```
.float-left { float: left; }
#random-box { background-color: #000; color: #fff; }
```

I always reasoned that the last is better due to there being less CSS (e.g. anything that is floated left can have the class "float-left" this means you don't have to repeat "float: left" for various different items) the only downside being that you end up with quite long CSS classes sometimes . . .

If I am right, in which cases should you use ID's? And more importantly are there any really useful website articles that tackle this issue head on?

Or is this a case of this not mattering, and doing it either way being generally accepted as fine?

Comment: Simple rule of thumb is: use ID's to identify something unique on your page, and classes to identify something which can be logically identified as a collection following some pattern, similarities, or anology..I guess you are already on the right path.. but sometimes its totally the designer's preference.

Comment: so say for example, a header for a page (Which will never be repeated again) should use Id's, where as elements in the main content area generally will us classes?

Comment: suppose you got a table and you want to have different colors for different rows, you can set the class of all the even rows to evenrow, odd rows class to oddrow, and now they form a logical pattern for your table - certainly you can't use ID's for them here right! So it is clear to use a ID for header as you speak, and classes for all the main content - is a personal preference. Now if you form a habit of dividing your content into logical groups to modify their style in one go better suits for "class" usage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I've settled mostly on using [OOCSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/) as my main philosophy when coding.

I could rabbit on, but I doubt many people will ever look at this question, and the link above provides a great starting point for questions like mine above.